# Не работает шорткод [caption] на страницах записей wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

На странице записи, после вставки изображения с [caption], сам шорткод выводится на странице, не срабатывает.

Результат: [image: результат ошибки]

Comment: Самописная тема?

Comment: Тут может быть только две проблемы: или шорткода не существует, или человек выводит контент в самописной теме через `get_the_content()`. Если второе, внимательно прочитайте как работает функция на кодексе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, только что разобрался в чем была проблема, может кому надо будет:
1. Новости выводились через созданный шаблон single.php. В этом файле контент выводился через the_content() и вот через него шорткод не работал. Когда переделал через файл content-page.php вывод то все стало на свои места